# How to save change state in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

While returning back from the link in the second tab i.e from swiggy, it always redirecting to first tab

How can I save the state change?

```
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openFood(event, 'Zomato')" id="defaultOpen">Zomato</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openFood(event, 'Swiggy')">Swiggy</button>
</div>

<div id="Zomato" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Zomato</h3>
  <a href="https://www.zomato.com/kingman-ks">Zomato</a>
</div>

<div id="Swiggy" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Swiggy</h3>
   <a href="https://www.swiggy.com/">Swiggy</a>
</div>
<script>
function openFood(evt, FoodVendor) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(FoodVendor).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put simply, your JavaScript runs each time the page is refreshed; when a user clicks one of the links in the DOM (or what you've written between html tags), the script is run from top to bottom with no idea of what happened previously.

State management is a difficult but common problem in modern user interfaces, which is why we have JavaScript libraries like [Angular](https://angular.io/), [React](https://reactjs.org), [Vue](https://vuejs.org/), [JQuery UI](https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/), and others to take care of the complex under-the-hood concerns and allow your UI's state to persist and your components to be reactive (i.e. a user clicks a tab and the active class is applied without a refresh).

If you need a super simple implementation that persists across refreshes you could:

1. Use [Local Storage or Session Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) to maintain the active tab, e.g.

```
window.localStorage.setItem('activeTab', 'Swiggy');
// after user refreshes
const id = window.localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
const el = document.getElementById(id);
el.className += "active";
// (you'll also have to remove the active class from the "default" active tab etc.)
```

2. Use a [query string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams), e.g.

```
// user navigates to https://yoursite.com/yourendpoint?activeTab=Swiggy
function checkForActiveTabQueryString() {
  const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  const activeTab = params.get("activeTab");

  if (activeTab) {
    const el = document.getElementById(activeTab);
    if (el) {
      el.className += "active";
    }
    // you'll have to remove the active class from the "default" tab, 
    // etc.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML5 [`LocalStorage Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to save some parameter for the current tab locally in the browser and get it back to make the last active tab selected on page reload. Check [this](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-keep-the-current-tab-active-on-page-reload-in-bootstrap.php) tutorial.

What I've **changed (add/remove)**:

1. Remove **DefaultOpen**

   But instead I added '**active**' class to `Zomato` Button. And set `display:none` to **tabcontent**.
2. Add **Local Storage**

   - Everytime the tab changes **i.e.** everytime `openFood()` is called,
     we save the currentState to localStorage with variable name
     **activeTab** (value is either 'Zomato' or 'Swiggy').

     `localStorage.setItem('activeTab', FoodVendor);`
   - When the page loads, we check **activeTab** value and decide which tab to open.

     ```
     $(document).ready(function(){
        var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
        /* Decide active tab */
        if (activeTab == 'Swiggy'){
          openFood('SwiggyTab', 'Swiggy');
        }
        // Default: open Zomato Tab
        else{
          openFood('ZomatoTab', 'Zomato');
        }
     });
     ```

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
    div.tabcontent{
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks active" id="ZomatoTab" onclick="openFood('ZomatoTab', 'Zomato')">Zomato</button>
  <button class="tablinks" id="SwiggyTab" onclick="openFood('SwiggyTab', 'Swiggy')">Swiggy</button>
</div>

<div id="Zomato" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Zomato</h3>
  <a href="https://www.zomato.com/kingman-ks">Zomato</a>
</div>

<div id="Swiggy" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Swiggy</h3>
   <a href="https://www.swiggy.com/">Swiggy</a>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //get activeTab from LocalStorage
        var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
        //Decide which tab to open
        if (activeTab == 'Swiggy'){
            openFood('SwiggyTab', 'Swiggy');
        }
        else{
            openFood('ZomatoTab', 'Zomato');
        }
    });
    function openFood(id, FoodVendor) {
      var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
      tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
      for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
      for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      
      document.getElementById(FoodVendor).style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById(id).className += " active";
      
      //Save the latest activeTab
      localStorage.setItem('activeTab', FoodVendor);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Getting error in console - ' Cannot read property 'currentTarget' of undefined'

Comment: Didn't get you? What shall i do

Comment: I see, it's caused by `event` parameter. It's undefined when calling the function on `.ready` function. Do you mind changing `openFood()` function, e.g passing unique button `id` instead of `event`?

Comment: Hey, I've set a unique id to both button, so instead of using `event` parameter, you can use element `id` parameter, and add `active` class to button with this particular id. What I'm trying to demonstrate here is how you can use `localStorage Object` to save the latest state and get the state back on refresh/load.

Comment: Great, glad it helped!